# Push multi-dimension array into another array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an multi-dimension array that i'm iterating through. Is there a way to put the contents of the array into a new multi-dimension array creating a new MDA? For example, the following code puts all indices of the original array into the new candies array if there's a match. Currently i'm doing

```
candies.push([product[0],product[1], etc...]);
```

I'm just trying to see if there's a faster/cleaner way to get that in there.

I tried:

```
candies.push(product);
```

but that didn't work. Here's the code i'm currently using

```
var sel = 'candy';
var candies = [];

   for(var i = 1; i < products.length; i++) {
      var product = products[i];
      for(var j = 0; j < product.length; j++) {

          if(sel==product[11]){
            candies.push([product[0],product[1],product[2],product[3],product[4],product[5],product[6],product[7],product[8],product[9],product[10],product[11],product[12]]);
          }

          break;

          }
      }
```

Comment: try https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: You are saying *into a new multi-dimension array*, but from what i see in your snippet `candy` will not be a multi-dimension array, or am i missing something here?

Comment: I'm basically saying if sel matches product[11], which if it does it's a candy, then add it to the multi-dimension array candies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A cleaner way of writing below line:

```
candies.push([product[0],product[1],product[2],product[3],product[4],product[5],product[6],product[7],product[8],product[9],product[10],product[11],product[12]]);
```

is:

```
candies.push(product.slice(0,13)]);
```

Sample example JSFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/1tf7w8tv/2/).

Best of luck.

(Mark this as answer if it serves your need.)